# How do I configure webpack for scss and bootstrap with ASP.NET project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I've got webpack up and running and can't quite figure our how to get .scss file compiled to be used with custom styling such as colors etc. Bootstrap is otherwise loaded fine.

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env = {}, argv = {}) => {

    const isProd = argv.mode === 'production';

    const config = {
        mode: argv.mode || 'development', // we default to development when no 'mode' arg is passed

        optimization: {
            minimize: true
        },
        entry: {
            main: './src/main.js'
        },
        output: {
            filename: isProd ? 'bundle-[chunkHash].js' : '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/dist'),
            publicPath: "/dist/"
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: isProd ? 'style-[contenthash].css' : 'style.css'
            }),
            new CompressionPlugin({
                filename: '[path].gz[query]',
                algorithm: 'gzip',
                test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
                threshold: 10240,
                minRatio: 0.8
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: '_LayoutTemplate.cshtml',
                filename: '../../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml', //the output root here is /wwwroot/dist so we ../../      
                inject: false
            })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'assets/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    return config;
};
```

I have node-sass installed which I think compiles it? Just not sure how to get it going.

Thanks,

Comment: When you build, is it compiling to your dist folder? Is it just not working on your devserver?

Comment: It's not no, I'm not entirely sure where to define the scss file, so that may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your CSS into your entrypoint. So in `main.js`, import your scss file like this...

```
import './path-to/file.scss
```